# What is the best practice for updating rails seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, seed

I have a rails application in production with seed data. We need to add more seed data, but using `rake db:populate` will replicate all the old seed data and of course we don't want to add the data to migrations.

What is the best method of adding extra seed data to the application?

Comment: So what I'm hearing is there is no way to do this properly. There should be a seed rake task like migrations that takes into account the seed data that has been entered so far. Maybe I'll make that.

Comment: Did you ever end up making this?

Answer (score 2):

### Stand on the Shoulders of Giants

Take a look at the **[SeedFu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu)** gem.

It allows you to create a seed file like this, that automatically links to one, or more, columns:

```
User.seed(:id,
  { id: 1, login: 'jon',   email: 'jon@example.com',   name: 'Jon'   },
  { id: 2, login: 'emily', email: 'emily@example.com', name: 'Emily' }
)
```

You can also update these seed files and it will handle updating the DB values.

This, in combination with **[Seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank)**, is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably going to have to build another rake task.  Or you could just do checks on each new row to see if it already exists.  It may take more time to run like that, but at least you won't have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I use a clunky workaround in my seed file to stop the same data being added twice.

```
if Therapy.count == 0
    therapies = Therapy.create([
        { :name => 'Peritoneal dialysis'
        },
        { :name => 'Haemodialysis'
        },
        { :name => 'Plasma therapy'
        },
        { :name => 'Laparotomy'
        },
        { :name => 'Haemofiltration'
        }
        ])
end
```

I suppose this could be modified to the following

```
   if Therapy.count == 0
                therapies = Therapy.create([
                    { :name => 'Peritoneal dialysis'
                    },
                    { :name => 'Haemodialysis'
                    },
                    { :name => 'Plasma therapy'
                    },
                    { :name => 'Laparotomy'
                    },
                    { :name => 'Haemofiltration'
                    }
                    ])
    elsif Therapy.count == 4
              therapies = Therapy.create([
                    { :name => 'NEW THERAPY'
                    }
                    ])
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you think there should be a rake task for something, you might want to check the available tasks.

```
rake -T seed
rake db:seed  # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
```

That being said [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) provides much better functionality IMHO